# Get data attribute from radio button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html convertd to haml:

```
%input#insurance_isp_payment{ checked: "checked", type: "radio", name: "insurance_isp_payment", price: 27.22, value: "single"}
27,22 €
```

And now I want to get this price value from radio button which is checked. I tried something like that:

```
$('input[name=insurance_isp_payment]:checked').data("price")
```

But this not work. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this : instead of `data()` use `attr()` to get the price value.

```
var price = $('input[name="insurance_isp_payment"]:checked').attr("price");
alert(price);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var price = $('input[name="insurance_isp_payment"]:checked').attr("data-price");
alert(price);
```

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=insurance_isp_payment]').on('change', function() {

var price = $('input[name="insurance_isp_payment"]:checked').attr("data-price");
alert(price);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-checked="yes" type="radio" name="insurance_isp_payment" value="100" checked data-price="100" />Single
<input data-checked="no" type="radio" name="insurance_isp_payment" value="200" data-price="200"/>Double
```